# Change default mail application without configuring mail.app

Tags: mail.app, email, gmail

I'd like to change my default application for handling mailto: links to be the gmail browser-based client. I'd like to do this *without* configuring the default mail.app. That means I cannot get to the mail.app preferences panel. Does anyone know how?

Comment: I just desperately need to vent my frustration about this. I mean really, who puts a default app config behind a mandatory account setup!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**RCDefaultApp**](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) allows you to pipe mailto: links to an app different to the app you have set as the default mail app.

[image]